# How to use Oracle Fusion Middleware with MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, oracle, business-intelligence, oracle-fusion-middleware

Is it possible to connect and process a MySQL database with Oracle Fusion Middleware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can.

First find a suitable jdbc driver, next create a connection pool and have your application fetch sessions from the connection pool.

Answer (score 3):

Sure.

Please follow steps bellow:

1-In Weblogic Console, select create net datasource.
Fill the name, JNDI path as you want, and select MySQL as database type.

[image]

2- Select the MySQL driver that fits your needs (its provided out-of-the-box).
[image]

3- Mark flags if you need XA connections or 2-phase commit.

[image]

4- Provide host, user and password.
[image]

Now your are good to go.